# Class ParseClient not found in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I keep on trying to get my program to work with back4app, so I used PHP development   to get it to work. I have already inserted my keys, etc, but for some reason, in the end it says "**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Parse\ParseClient' not found in mycode.php"
Here is my code:

```
require "parse-php-sdk/autoload.php";

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;

$appid = "x";
$rest = "x";
$masterKey = "x";

ParseClient::initialize( $appid, $rest, $masterKey );
ParseClient::setServerURL('https://parseapi.back4app.com', '/');
```

And here is the code that is placed in autoload.php

```
$base_dir = defined('PARSE_SDK_DIR') ? PARSE_SDK_DIR : __DIR__.'/src/Parse/';
```

And yes, I do have the right directory for the classes.
I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It look like wrong path to this library, check it! I recommend you use composer to install and autoload

Comment: I still don't understand how to use the composer though

Comment: You have in documentation

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk

Install composer

Comment: I already tried that composer but it really confuses me. First of all I do all my php coding in the web host since I don't even do it so much and I only need it for this temporary program so I can't install composer. So I don't know what to do without it. Also, it is the correct path to it, for sure. I don't nkow what else could be wrong.

Comment: I am using the parse-php-sdk folder, inside of that is the autoload, then there is another folder called "sc", inside of that is "Parse", inside of that are all teh classes. I don't think that it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use it like this:

```
Parse\ParseClient::initialize(..)
```

since in the beginning you init. Parse SDK as use Parse\ParseClient 
you will need to add `Parse\` before any class you will use.